# Populating a List with a contiguous range of integers

Tags: java, guava

I'd like to have a list which contains the integers in the range 1 to 500.  Is there some way to create this list using Guava (or just plain Java) without having to loop through the range and add the values individually within my own code?

Comment: Whatever you do, there will be a loop (in your code or in the helper method you use).

Comment: (Is editing questions to include their own answers a thing we're doing now?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using Guava, you can resort to a `Range`: https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Range.html

Of course, there will still be loops in your code, but they just might be hidden from the code for simplicity sake.

For instance:

```
Range<Integer> yourValues = Range.closed(1, 500);
```

Check https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/RangesExplained for some more examples.

Keep in mind that if you *do* need to eventually iterate over the `Range`, you cannot do so directly, only through using `DiscreteDomains.integers()`.

Comment: Thanks this pointed me in the right direction.  The final code I needed was ImmutableList.copyOf(ContiguousSet.create(Range.closed(1, 500), DiscreteDomain.integers()))

Comment: @jgm You don't have to do the `ImmutableList` copy because `ContiguousSet` is already an immutable collection (`ImmutableSortedSet`) which has `asLst()` method returning `ImmutableList` view.

Comment: BTW Creating `ImmutableList` from `ContiguousSet` which has unbounded range like `Range.atLeast(1)` can result in OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 136):

The new, Java 8 way:

```
List<Integer> range = IntStream.range(1, 501).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is pretty cool; however, do you not receive a cast warning/compiler error?

Comment: No, do you? If so it might be because you did not enable support for Java 8 language features (or older -- here I'm thinking type inference) in your IDE (it's possible to have a Java 8 JDK, have access to all the libraries and not have the language features support).

Comment: With Java 16 you can make it even shorter: `IntStream.range(1, 501).boxed().toList()`

Answer (score 1):

Btw. if it is only to be used in some sort of iteration, you could simply create a basic class which implements the `Iterable` interface, to skip the insertion altogether.

Something like this:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class IntegerRange implements Iterable<Integer> {
    private int start, end;

    public IntegerRange(int start, int end) {
        if (start <= end) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        } else {
            this.start = end;
            this.end = start;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new IntegerRangeIterator();
    }

    private class IntegerRangeIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
        private int current = start;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current <= end;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer next() {
            return current++;
        }
    }
}
```

Which could be used in some way like this:

```
Iterable<Integer> range = new IntegerRange(1, 500);

for (int i : range) {
    // ... do something with the integer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Apache Commons [IntRange](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/IntRange.html) utility

E.g.

```
    private List<Integer> getAllIntegerRange(Integer firstValue, Integer secondValue) {
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    IntRange rang = new IntRange(firstValue, secondValue);
    int[] ranges = rang.toArray();
    for (int i : ranges) {
        values.add(i);
    }
    return values;
}
```