# Java add elements to list

Tags: java

How can I do this in short way without iterating just giving 5?

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        l.add(i);
    }
```

Comment: Note: the alternatives use iteration, it's just that you don't see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

or with Java 8 streams:

```
List<Integer> l = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 7):

```
l.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Or, you can initialize it with the specified values

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but 5 is dynamic it can be 4, 7 etc .

Comment: @Lusi As Peter Lawrey said in the comment, even if you do find a utility method in some library that does this in one line, in the background it also uses iteration so you might as well write your own.

Answer (score 0):

You need some upper bound for your loop. If you don't hard-code it as you did in the snippet, the value must come from somewhere.

You could use this constructor for the ArrayList data structure:
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)
 and bypass the loop altogether, but you won't have the initializers .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Guava Ranges](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/RangesExplained) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711147/populating-a-list-with-a-contiguous-range-of-integers).
In short, 
`ContiguousSet.create(Range.closed(1, 500), DiscreteDomain.integers()).asList()`

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is using Java 8 stream:

```
List<Integer> intList = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: you're missing the `boxed()` call which converts your `IntStream` to `Stream<Integer>` so you actually can collect the values