# Populating a List with a contiguous range of shorts

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23675131/14731 provides a nice solution for generating a list of contiguous integers. Seeing as JDK8 does not provide a `ShortStream` class, how would you generate a list of contiguous shorts?

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

`List<Short> range = ShortStream.range(0, 500).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`

where the output contains a list of shorts, from 0 to 500 inclusive.

Comment: I assume the non-stream answer from that post was not to your liking?

Comment: Use an `IntStream` and narrow the values.

Comment: @River sorry, I should have clarified. I want a Stream-related solution if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<Short> range = 
    IntStream.range(0, 500).mapToObj(i -> (short) i).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Good answer. Please take a look at this follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30790665/14731