# Generating a short[] using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Building upon [Populating a List with a contiguous range of shorts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30789966/14731) I tried generating an array of primitive shorts. This turned out to be surprisingly harder than expected.

`Short[] range = IntStream.range(0, 500).mapToObj(value -> (short) value).toArray(Short[]::new)` worked but:

`short[] range = IntStream.range(0, 500).mapToObj(value -> (short) value).toArray(short[]::new)` generated a compiler error:

```
method toArray in interface Stream<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: IntFunction<A[]>
  found: short[]::new
  reason: inference variable A has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: short
    upper bounds: Object
  where A,T are type-variables:
    A extends Object declared in method <A>toArray(IntFunction<A[]>)
    T extends Object declared in interface Stream
```

This seems to be an intersection of two problems:

1. The primitive Stream APIs do not provide an implementation for `short`s.
2. The non-primitive Stream APIs do not seem to provide a mechanism to return a primitive array.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're making your own life complicated by using short instead of int. That won't bring any performance or memory advantage, but make your code harder to write. I've not used a short, or seen a short in any API, for years.

Comment: @JBNizet I get that, but the field corresponds to a database column of type `short` (I cannot change the database schema for legacy reasons). By storing `short` up-front I prevent the possibility of a casting error at the last minute, before sending the data to the database.

Comment: You correctly understand the problem.  The streams library designers decided it wasn't worth adding ShortStream etc., unboxing does not interoperate with generics, and adding special `toShortArray()` methods would also not work because you could call them on, say, a `Stream<Path>`.

Comment: If you really want an array of shorts, I would simply use a for loop rather than trying to use streams.

Comment: @JBNizet can you elaborate on where there is no performance or memory advantage to using a short for something? It's literally half the number of bytes of integers. We're working with efficient data storage here for an embedded system, so a 50% reduction in data size is significant.

Comment: @GuyPaddock For performance reasons, the JVM could be memory-aligning shorts to 32-bit or 64-bit boundaries. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1496881/14731 and a counter-argument at https://lemire.me/blog/2012/05/31/data-alignment-for-speed-myth-or-reality/. Point is: we don't know what is going on under the hood. If I were you, I'd find a way to measure actual memory usage for your particular setup (hardware/software) and if it makes a difference then by all means go for it.

Comment: @JBNizet I disagree. I worked on a streaming application where we beg for saving a single byte, that's merely due to the amount of data we have to ingest and process every second! Hence, I had to use `short` a few times!

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/) library. It extends standand streams with additional methods. One of the goals of my library is better interoperation with old code. In particular it has [`IntStreamEx.toShortArray()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/IntStreamEx.html#toShortArray--) and [`IntStreamEx.of(short...)`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/IntStreamEx.html#of-short...-):

```
short[] numbers = IntStreamEx.range(500).toShortArray();
short[] evenNumbers = IntStreamEx.of(numbers).map(x -> x*2).toShortArray();
```

Note that it's still the stream of `int` numbers. When calling `toShortArray()`, they are automatically converted to `short` type using `(short)` cast operation, thus overflow is possible. So use with care.

There are also `IntStreamEx.toByteArray()`, `IntStreamEx.toCharArray()`, and `DoubleStreamEx.toFloatArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way would be implementing a custom `Collector`.

```
class ShortCollector {
    public static Collector<Integer,ShortCollector,short[]> TO_ARRAY
        =Collector.of(ShortCollector::new, ShortCollector::add,
                      ShortCollector::merge, c->c.get());

    short[] array=new short[100];
    int pos;

    public void add(int value) {
        int ix=pos;
        if(ix==array.length) array=Arrays.copyOf(array, ix*2);
        array[ix]=(short)value;
        pos=ix+1;
    }
    public ShortCollector merge(ShortCollector c) {
        int ix=pos, cIx=c.pos, newSize=ix+cIx;
        if(array.length<newSize) array=Arrays.copyOf(array, newSize);
        System.arraycopy(c.array, 0, array, ix, cIx);
        return this;
    }
    public short[] get() {
        return pos==array.length? array: Arrays.copyOf(array, pos);
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like

```
short[] array=IntStream.range(0, 500).boxed().collect(ShortCollector.TO_ARRAY);
```

The drawback is that `Collector`s only work for reference types (as Generics doesn’t support primitive types), thus you have to resort to `boxed()` and collectors can’t utilize information about the number of elements (if ever available). Thus, the performance is likely to be far worse than `toArray()` on a primitive data stream.

So, a solution striving for higher performance (I limit this to the single threaded case) will look like this:

```
public static short[] toShortArray(IntStream is) {
    Spliterator.OfInt sp = is.spliterator();
    long l=sp.getExactSizeIfKnown();
    if(l>=0) {
        if(l>Integer.MAX_VALUE) throw new OutOfMemoryError();
        short[] array=new short[(int)l];
        sp.forEachRemaining(new IntConsumer() {
            int ix;
            public void accept(int value) {
                array[ix++]=(short)value;
            }
        });
        return array;
    }
    final class ShortCollector implements IntConsumer {
        int bufIx, currIx, total;
        short[][] buffer=new short[25][];
        short[] current=buffer[0]=new short[64];

        public void accept(int value) {
            int ix = currIx;
            if(ix==current.length) {
                current=buffer[++bufIx]=new short[ix*2];
                total+=ix;
                ix=0;
            }
            current[ix]=(short)value;
            currIx=ix+1;
        }
        short[] toArray() {
            if(bufIx==0)
                return currIx==current.length? current: Arrays.copyOf(current, currIx);
            int p=0;
            short[][] buf=buffer;
            short[] result=new short[total+currIx];
            for(int bIx=0, e=bufIx, l=buf[0].length; bIx<e; bIx++, p+=l, l+=l)
                System.arraycopy(buf[bIx], 0, result, p, l);
            System.arraycopy(current, 0, result, p, currIx);
            return result;
        }
    }
    ShortCollector c=new ShortCollector();
    sp.forEachRemaining(c);
    return c.toArray();
}
```

You may use it like

```
short[] array=toShortArray(IntStream.range(0, 500));
```